# pythonでGUIを用いて、ニュースサイトから記事をスクレイピングするツールを作ろうとしています

Tags: python, gui

GUI(wxpython)を用いてニュースサイトから記事をスクレイピングし、Lineへ送信するツールを作ろうとしております！

記事数をカウントするコードが上手くいってない状況です。
送信上限の1,000文字を「news」へ一度に書き込んで、そこだけ送信してしまっているようです。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
こちらの最後のフィードバックとしまして
count += 1のインデントがtry文上にあり、そこを間違えておりました。
正しくは、for文と同じインデントにない為にカウントが機能しなかったようです。

```
#Yahooニュースの記事は1ページで最大25件なので、それに合わせています
#記事の取得数をカウントさせ、希望数に達した時点でブレイクする
        #1000文字の送信上限を考慮し、13記事まで取得した時点で次のメッセージで送信するようにしている
            count = 0
            stop_count = 0
            stop_count = self.combo_box_4.GetClientData(self.combo_box_4.GetSelection())
            
            for title ,date ,url in zip(news_title, news_date, news_urls):

                if count > stop_count:
                    break
                elif count <= 13:
                    news += '{} ({}) {}'.format(title, date, url) + '\r\n'
                else:
                    news2 += '{} ({}) {}'.format(title, date, url) + '\r\n'

            count += 1
```

こちらが完成したコードとなります。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
#
# generated by wxGlade 1.1.0pre on Thu Jan 13 14:50:45 2022
#

import wx
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime

# begin wxGlade: dependencies
# end wxGlade

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade

class Myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: Myframe.__init__
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((800, 600))
        self.SetTitle("記事スクレイピング")

        grid_sizer_1 = wx.GridSizer(4, 3, 0, 0)

        label_4 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"取得したいジャンル：")
        label_4.SetFont(wx.Font(15, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 0, ""))
        grid_sizer_1.Add(label_4, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALL, 5)

        #コンボボックスの中身リストを作り、内部データとしてURLを埋め込む
        self.combo_box_3 = wx.ComboBox(self, wx.ID_ANY,"", style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN | wx.CB_READONLY)
        self.combo_box_3.Append(u"主要", 'https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/top-picks')
        self.combo_box_3.Append(u"国内", 'https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/domestic')
        self.combo_box_3.Append(u"国際", 'https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/world')
        self.combo_box_3.Append(u"経済", 'https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/business')
        self.combo_box_3.Append(u"エンタメ", 'https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/entertainment')
        self.combo_box_3.Append(u"スポーツ", 'https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/sports')
        self.combo_box_3.Append(u"IT", 'https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/it')
        self.combo_box_3.Append(u"科学", 'https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/science')
        self.combo_box_3.Append(u"ライフ", 'https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/life')
        self.combo_box_3.Append(u"地域", 'https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/local')
        self.combo_box_3.SetMinSize((200, 23))
        self.combo_box_3.SetFont(wx.Font(9, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 0, "Yu Gothic UI"))
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.combo_box_3, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALL, 5)

        grid_sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 2, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 5)

        label_5 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"一度に取得したい記事数：")
        label_5.SetFont(wx.Font(15, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 0, ""))
        grid_sizer_1.Add(label_5, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.combo_box_4 = wx.ComboBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, "", style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN | wx.CB_READONLY)
        #str型を変換する方法が分からなかったので、愚直に内部データからかえてます
        self.combo_box_4.Append("1",1)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("2",2)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("3",3)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("4",4)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("5",5)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("6",6)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("7",7)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("8",8)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("9",9)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("10",10)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("11",11)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("12",12)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("13",13)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("14",14)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("15",15)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("16",16)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("17",17)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("18",18)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("19",19)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("20",20)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("21",21)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("22",22)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("23",23)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("24",24)
        self.combo_box_4.Append("25",25)



        self.combo_box_4.SetMinSize((200, 23))
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.combo_box_4, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALL, 5)

        grid_sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 2, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 5)

        grid_sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 2, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 5)


        self.button_5 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"実行")
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button_5, 2, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 5)

        self.button_6 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"キャンセル")
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button_6, 2, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.LEFT, 5)

        self.SetSizer(grid_sizer_1)

        self.Layout()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExec, self.button_5)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCancel, self.button_6)
        # end wxGlade

    def OnExec(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
        global news,news2,count

        try:

            url = self.combo_box_3.GetClientData(self.combo_box_3.GetSelection())
            soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

            d_today = datetime.date.today()
            news = "↓↓↓ 本日" + str(d_today) + "のニュース↓↓↓" + '\r\n'
            news2 = "ニュースの続き"'\r\n'

            # URL取得
            news_urls = []
            for li_tag in soup.find_all('li', {'class', 'newsFeed_item'}):
                try:
                    news_urls.append(li_tag.find(
                        'a', {'class', 'newsFeed_item_link'})['href'])
                except:
        # 広告を読み飛ばす
                    pass

        # 記事の題目と記事の発表日時
            news_title = []
            news_date = []
            div_tags = soup.find_all('div', {'class', 'newsFeed_item_title'})
            for div_tag in div_tags:
                news_title.append(div_tag.text)
                news_date.append(div_tag.next_sibling.find('time').text)

        #記事の取得数をカウントさせ、希望数に達した時点でブレイクする
        #1000文字の送信上限を考慮し、12記事まで取得した時点で次のメッセージで送信するようにしている
            count = 0
            stop_count = 0
            stop_count = self.combo_box_4.GetClientData(self.combo_box_4.GetSelection())

            for title ,date ,url in zip(news_title, news_date, news_urls):

                if count > stop_count:
                    break
                elif count <= 12:
                    news += '{} ({}) {}'.format(title, date, url) + '\r\n'
                else:
                    news2 += '{} ({}) {}'.format(title, date, url) + '\r\n'

                count += 1

            def send_line_notify(notification_message):
            #LINEに通知する
                line_notify_token = '(トークン名)xGhyoBa589TcZI4cV'
                line_notify_api = 'https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify'
                headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {line_notify_token}'}
                data = {'message': f'message: {notification_message}'}
                requests.post(line_notify_api, headers = headers, data = data)

            def main():
                #print(matome)
                send_line_notify(news)
                send_line_notify(news2)
            if __name__ == "__main__":
                main()

        except Exception as e:
                import traceback
                print(traceback.format_exc())
                dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 'エラーが発生しました。入力内容を確認してください。',
                                    'エラー',
                                    wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR
                                    )
                dlg.ShowModal()
                dlg.Destroy()
        else:
                dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 'スクレイピング完了しました',
                                    '完了',
                                    wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION
                                    )
                dlg.ShowModal()
                dlg.Destroy()

    def OnCancel(self, event):  # wxGlade: Myframe.<event_handler>
        self.Destroy()

# end of class Myframe

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = Myframe(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

# end of class MyApp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: `int(stop_count)` でよいかもしれませんが、GUI で件数が選択されていない場合はエラーになりますので、デフォルト値を決めておくとよさそうです。

Comment: metropolis様ありがとうございます！
ご指摘いただいた通りに修正しましたところ、エラーを出さず、実行完了できるコードとなりました！
なのですが、記事数カウントが機能してせず、送信上限の1000文字分までしか送らないプログラムとなっているようです。
再び読み漁りながら修正してみようと思います！
`count = 0
 stop_count = 0
 stop_count =self.combo_box_4.GetClientData(self.combo_box_4.GetSelection())
            
            for title ,date ,url in zip(news_title, news_date, news_urls):

                if count > int(stop_count):
                    break
                elif count <= 7:`
文字数の関係で問題コードは省略させていただいてます。

Comment: 完成致しました、お知恵を貸していただき有難うございました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.combo_box_3.GetValue()` とする場合は表示名(「主要」とか「国内」など)を取得します。なので、それを以下の様に書き換えます。

```py
    def OnExec(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
        global news,news2,news3

        try:
            self.combo_box_3.GetValue()
            self.combo_box_4.GetValue()
            # url = self.combo_box_3.GetValue()
            url = self.combo_box_3.GetClientData(self.combo_box_3.GetSelection())
```

それから、`try ~ except` の範囲が長大で、かつ、エラー内容の表示が行われていませんので、`stacktrace` を表示する様にしておく方がよろしいかと思います。

```
        except Exception as e:
                import traceback
                print(traceback.format_exc())
                dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 'エラーが発生しました。入力内容を確認してください。',
                                    'エラー',
                                    wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR
                                    )

                           :
```

Comment: metropolis様のお陰で一歩前進する事が出来ました！
現在は新たに出てきた型エラー(コンボボックス内の文字列型扱いの数字をint型にする)を修正しております。
型エラーは何とかなると思いますので、修正後また記事にて進捗報告させていただきます！！
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ユーザー名\testcode2-2.py", line 117, in OnExec
    if count > stop_count:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```